# Drag and Drop to taskbar notification area with WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi, shell, taskbar

Is it possible to implement drag and drop behavior in the notification area of the windows taskbar? Like having the icon there that can monitor something dragged and dropped on it. I suppose it should be a little bit tricky (if ever possible)

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice, but the notification area of the windows taskbar is all but gone. Windows XP's notification area shrinks a lot and even when expaned, still hides a wide variety of icons that are unchanged. Windows Vista - who cares what it does, but Windows 7 refines it further, and only shows most of the notification icons when a ^ button is clicked.
It looks like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

No, drag-n-drop is not available in the Taskbar's notification area, or on your application's taskbar button(s).  You can only accept drag-n-drop from within your application's actual window(s).